# Laptop screen goes black every once in a while

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

My laptop is just a week old. It used to sleep randomly even when I'm using it, but i took it to get it fixed.

Now it no longer sleeps but it goes black every once in a while, and I can't understand why.

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium. Any help or info will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Control Panel` and then `Power Options`.

Otherwise it will be better to use your warranty.